# JavaCC Parser Issue

Tags: parsing, bnf, javacc

I am trying to read a text but running into issue. Please note I just got started with JavaCC.

```
"token1 /path1/*/path /token2"

TOKEN:{
token1: ("token1") :someState
}

someStateTOKEN  :

{
  token: ("/token")? 
}
```

The error:

```
Encountered " <token2> " "" at line **, column 8. 
Was expecting one of: <RESULT> ... <SPACE> …
```

Heres the Expression :

```
tok=<token1>(<SPACE_CHAR>)?val=<RESULT>(<token2>)?(<SPACE>)?
```

Comment: Could you add the exception or stacktrace?

Comment: Encountered " <token2> " "" at line **, column 8.
                                                                     Was expecting one of:
    <RESULT> ...
    <SPACE> …
                                                                               Heres the Expression :
 tok=<token1>(<SPACE_CHAR>)?val=<RESULT>(<token2>)?(<SPACE>)?

Comment: Can you post (or link to) the complete .jj file and the input you expect to be parsable?